# How do I create a new HTTP::Daemon in perl without root permisson?

Tags: perl, http, proxy, cgi, daemon

Line 271 from HTTP::Proxy is this:

```
my $daemon = HTTP::Daemon->new(%args) or die "Cannot initialize proxy daemon: $!";
```

When I try to run this script:

```
use CGI;
use CGI::Carp(fatalsToBrowser);

use HTTP::Proxy;

my $proxy = HTTP::Proxy->new( port => 8080 ); # Edit: I have tried other ports, too, including 3123, 32789, etc.

$proxy->start;
```

I get this error message from the browser:

## Software error:

#### Cannot initialize proxy daemon: Operation not permitted at HTTP/Proxy.pm line 271.

For help, please send mail to this site's webmaster, giving this error message 
and the time and date of the error.

I assume this is because I need root permission. Are there any ports I can use that don't require root permission? I don't have the root password to the server.

Edit: Apparently I'm supposed to be able to start it without root with 1025 or greater. How would I set up a stacktrace?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure port 8080 is not already in use on that server?  netstat -an ¦ grep 8080

Comment: Purely theoretically, for higher # ports, you shouldn't need root perms. At this point, you may want to start your server with a debugger and trace where exactly the error is coming from (Looking at source, it is probably from `IO::Socket` or `IO::Handle` constructors).

Comment: Are you on some weird Linux with strange security model? (e.g. SELinux)? People ran into cryptic permission errors on that.

Comment: @DVK I'm on i386 FreeBSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any port (that is not already in use) above 1025.  If you are getting that message in your browser (on port 8080?), your daemon is already successfully using that port.  I'm not sure what other permission issues it might entail.  You could check the documentation or try `strace`

Comment: @Leo, `strace` is a utility that lists all the system calls (and their return codes), that you're program makes.  You'll just do `strace ./myscript.pl`.  It will take some time to read the output if you're new at it.  Look for a permission denied error somewhere in the output though.